# Troubles comprehending Boolean Algebra

Tags: boolean-logic, simplify

I am going through my Boolean Algebra book trying do some of the problems and I am looking for some help with regards to one wanting a function simplified using only DeMorgan's relationships and Involution.

f(A,B,C,D) = [A + (BCD)']*[(AD)' + B(C'+A)]

I attempted to reduce as follows:

[A + B' + C' + D']*[A' + D' + (B(C' + A))'] <-- Attempting Involution 

[A + B' + C' + D']*[A' + D' + B' + C'' * A'] 
[A + B' + C' + D']*[A' + D' + B' + CA'] 

[A + B' + C' + D']*[A' + B' + D']

I am wondering if the steps I took are valid or am I a bit off base?

Answer (score 0):

At the first step, you have an error

```
[(AD)' + B(C'+A)] = [A' + D' + B(C' + A)]
```

or

```
[(AD)' + B(C'+A)] = [A' + D' + (B(C' + A))'']
```